# Formula for calculating residues

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, analysis

I don't understand the following formula for calculating residues. We have proven the following:

> If $f$ has a pole at $z_0$ of order $k$ or less, then we have $\text{Res}_{z_0} f(z) = \frac 1 {(k-1)!} \frac{d^{k-1}}{dz^{k-1}}|_{z_0} (z-z_0)^k f(z)$.

Then we have this corollary:

> If $g$ and $h$ are holomorphic at $z_0$ and $h$ has a simple null there (meaning $h(z_0)=0$ and $h'(z_0) \neq 0$), then we have: $\text{Res}_{z_0} \frac{g(z)}{h(z)} = \frac{g(z_0)}{h'(z_0)}$.

I don't understand how this follows from the first lemma. Simple null means that it is a pole of order $1$ because if it's of higher order, we wouldn't have $h'(z_0) \neq 0$. So applying the lemma, we have $k=1$, but then we get $\text{Res}_{z_0} \frac{g(z)}{h(z)} = \frac 1 {0!} \frac{d^{0}}{dz^{0}}|_{z_0} (z-z_0)^1 \frac{g(z)}{h(z)} = (z-z_0) \frac{g(z)}{h(z)} |_{z_0} $ . Don't we get a limit here? Because it's of the form $0 \cdot \infty$?

Comment: I think that there's a hidden convention about all these (rather silly, imho) formulas: one is meant to remove all removable singularities before using them. If you are working more carefully, as you seem to be, then agreed, you'll need to take a limit at some later stage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first formula is not quite correct.  You do not find the residue by substituting $z=z_0$ in the right-hand side expression, you get it by taking the **limit** as $z$ approaches $z_0$.

Now take $k=1$ and find the required limit by using L'Hopital's Rule.  This will give your second result.

Comment: @ancientmathematician No.  If $f$ has a pole at $z_0$ then it is not defined at $z_0$.  You have to take a limit.

Answer (score 0):

The lemma you have written is incomplete as it is applicable only when $k \ge2$.We discuss a case of $k=1$.
By simple null of $h(z) \ at \ z_{0}$, we mean there is an analytic function $w(z) such \ that \ w(z_{0}) \ne \ 0$ and that $h(z)=(z-z_{0})^1 w(z). $
In terms of poles, if you want to analyse, $\frac{1}{h(z)} \ has \ a \ simple \ pole \ at\ z_{0}$ which leads to the fact that your function $ f(z) =\frac{g(z)}{h(z)}$ too has a simple pole at $z_{0}$.
Now you use a result that if f has a simple pole at $z_{0}$ , $Res_{z=z_{0}} f(z) =lim_{z →z_{0}} (z-z_{0})f(z) $

$=lim_{z →z_{0}} (z-z_{0}) \frac{g(z)}{h(z)}$

> Because of the case we're having $f=\frac{g}{h}$

$Res_{z=z_{0}} f(z)=lim_{z →z_{0}}\frac{g(z)}{(\frac{h(z)}{z-z_{0}})}$
$=lim_{z →z_{0}}\frac{g(z)}{(\frac{h(z)-h(z_{0})}{z-z_{0}})}$
=$\frac{g(z_{0})}{h'(z_{0}) }$